# Angular eslint is very slow

Tags: angular, performance, eslint

Recently I have migrated our linting from tslint to the new angular eslint solution. my problem here is that is is very slow now! for a semi-big project it is taking about 5 minutes to lint! Last thing I could check was the builder options in the `angular.json` file, it is like this which takes long:

```json
"lint": {
  "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
  "options": {
    "lintFilePatterns": [
      "projects/blueprint-core-components/**/*.ts",
      "projects/blueprint-core-components/**/*.html"
    ]
  }
}
```

but when I add files one by one (not with wildcard) it grows little by little meaning that it is linting files one by one not all together and that means if I have ~300 files in my project it should take ~300x1s=300sec !!

should be really like this? or something is wrong here?

Comment: Agreed, the angular docs are insufficient and the performance is an incredible downgrade.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular project with eslint is super slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68628738/angular-project-with-eslint-is-super-slow)