# Angular project with eslint is super slow

Tags: angular-cli, eslint, typescript-eslint

I have an Angular12 project composed of 590 TypeScript files. When I do `ng lint` it runs TSLint and finishes in about 5 seconds. Nonetheless, I tried upgrading to eslint following the instructions on this [official video](https://youtu.be/IDBdtQlugtw) from Angular, and now `ng lint` takes more than 10 minutes (I actually didn't let the process finish, I stopped it at the 10 minutes mark).

I tried to isolate the issue to know if the cause was `ng` or `eslint` so I installed eslint globally with `npm i -g eslint` and run it with timing information for a single file:

```
time TIMING=1 eslint /home/user/my-file.ts
```

And even for this single file it took more than 2 minutes. It is odd that `eslint` is reporting each rule took just some milliseconds, whereas Linux says it took 148 seconds (which is accurate, it took more than 2 minutes):

```
Rule                                        | Time (ms) | Relative
:-------------------------------------------|----------:|--------:
@angular-eslint/no-conflicting-lifecycle    |     0.342 |    35.9%
@angular-eslint/no-input-rename             |     0.163 |    17.1%
@angular-eslint/template/banana-in-box      |     0.161 |    16.9%
@angular-eslint/no-output-rename            |     0.103 |    10.9%
@angular-eslint/component-class-suffix      |     0.100 |    10.5%
@angular-eslint/contextual-lifecycle        |     0.083 |     8.7%
@angular-eslint/directive-class-suffix      |     0.000 |     0.0%
@angular-eslint/no-empty-lifecycle-method   |     0.000 |     0.0%
@angular-eslint/no-host-metadata-property   |     0.000 |     0.0%
@angular-eslint/no-inputs-metadata-property |     0.000 |     0.0%
Rule | Time (ms) | Relative
:----|----------:|--------:
TIMING=1 eslint   148.14s user 4.47s system 190% cpu 1:19.96 total
```

How can I make eslint go faster?

Comment: None of the answers are satisfactory, in fact it's a massive blow to the Angular community to have a much worse performing linter being implemented #angular

Comment: I agree with @SebastianScholle, if we have to spend so much time tweaking a tool that's supposed to help us write better software, instead of focusing on the software itself, it defies the purpose. Tslint did a great job and somebody needs to revive the project.

Answer (score 7):

The underlying issue is still the overhead of the TypeScript compiler generating an AST (Abstract Syntax Tree), and the @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree work of converting this AST to an ESLint compatible AST.

However, there are some minor tweaks:

- Set up `.eslintignore` to ignore irrelevant directories like `node_modules` and non-TypeScript files
- Use the `--cache` flag when running eslint: `eslint --cache \*\*/\_.ts.` Store the info about processed files in order to only operate on the changed ones, or you may config the `angular.json` file's `lint` section with `"cache": true`.

There is also a whole article on [TypeScript performance](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Performance) which recommends:

- Set up `tsconfig.json` with the include property to specify only input folders in a project with TypeScript files that should be compiled.
- Avoid adding too many exclude and include folders, since TypeScript files must be discovered by walking through included directories, so running through many folders can actually slow down compilation.

Answer (score 6):

### Check the Notes on Performance in the Angular es-lint guide

I suggest carefully reading [through this section titled **Notes on Performance**](https://github.com/angular-eslint/angular-eslint#notes-on-performance) of the Angular ts-lint to es-lint migration guide.

You can start debugging your problem by running the following command:

```
DEBUG=typescript-eslint:* ng lint
```

You will get an enormous amount of output, but there could be some valuable information in there.

- Check (in one of the first lines) whether the expected `tsconfig` files are loaded.
- Check the output for files that are actually not supposed to be part of the linting process (i.e. from `node_modules` folder or `dist` folder, etc). This might expose some configuration issues for which you have to dig deeper.

Also check whether you get a lot of output as follows:

> **typescript-eslint:typescript-estree:createProjectProgram** Creating project program for: *path\to\your\file* +0ms 
> **typescript-eslint:typescript-estree:createWatchProgram** File did not belong to any existing programs, moving to create/update. *path\to\your\file* +0ms 
> **typescript-eslint:typescript-estree:createWatchProgram** Creating watch program for *path\to\your\file* +0ms

If that is the case have a good look at the files and path names inside your `tsconfig`. Specifically "baseUrl", "include" and "exclude" paths.

---

**Note:** *I had for example "exclude" paths for spec files, but because of a configuration issue they were actually not excluded correctly and creating project programs for these files individually was slowing down the linting dramatically*.

---

### Consider limiting linting to changes only

If after resolving all performance issues mentioned above does still not give you the performance you were hoping for you could also consider limiting the linting to changed files only.

This can be done by using the "cache" option in the lint options in your `angular.json` file (normally the --cache flag for eslint):

```
"lint": {
  "builder": "@angular-eslint/builder:lint",
  "options": {
    "cache": true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**First** I would *double check* [`parserOptions` ref GitHub](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/docs/getting-started/linting/TYPED_LINTING.md#performance), if its hitting the entire repo...

If thats the case,

- you can try and solve it by renaming `tsconfig.json` in the root to `tsconfig.base.json` and inside `packages/some-package/.eslintrc.json` specified `parserOptions.project` as `path.resolve(__dirname, './tsconfig.json')`.
- In my case the `parserOptions.project` was configured to `./tsconfig.json` and I guess in this case `eslint` tried to run tsc on the entire repo instead of one package which affected the performance.

---

**Second**, also consider this nice explanation [here](https://duncanleung.com/why-slow-plugin-typescript-eslint-performance-issues/) with some suggestions.

Per [his](http://The%20underlying%20issue%20is%20still%20the%20overhead%20of%20the%20TypeScript%20compiler%20generating%20an%20AST,%20and%20the%20@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree%20work%20of%20converting%20this%20AST%20to%20an%20ESLint%20compatible%20AST.%20%20However,%20there%20are%20some%20minor%20tweaks:%20%20Set%20up%20.eslintignore%20to%20ignore%20irrelevant%20directories%20like%20node_modules%20and%20non-typescript%20files%20Use%20the%20--cache%20flag%20when%20running%20eslint:%20eslint%20--cache%20%5C*%5C*/%5C_.ts.%20Store%20the%20info%20about%20processed%20files%20in%20order%20to%20only%20operate%20on%20the%20changed%20ones.%20There%20is%20also%20a%20whole%20article%20on%20TypeScript%20performance%20which%20recommends:%20%20Set%20up%20tsconfig.json%20with%20the%20include%20property%20to%20specify%20only%20input%20folders%20in%20a%20project%20with%20TypeScript%20files%20that%20should%20be%20compiled.%20Avoid%20adding%20too%20many%20exclude%20and%20include%20folders,%20since%20TypeScript%20files%20must%20be%20discovered%20by%20walking%20through%20included%20directories,%20so%20running%20through%20many%20folders%20can%20actually%20slow%20down%20compilation.) recommendations:

*"...The underlying issue is still the overhead of the TypeScript compiler generating an AST, and the @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree work of converting this AST to an ESLint compatible AST."*

His post offered some nice suggestions including caching

- Set up `.eslintignore` to ignore irrelevant directories like node_modules and non-typescript files
  Use the `--cache` flag when running eslint: `eslint --cache \*\*/\_.ts`. Store the info about processed files in order to only operate on the changed ones.
  There is also a whole article on TypeScript performance which recommends:

Answer (score -1):

For some reasons, ***removing*** from `tsconfig.json`

```
"exclude": [
    ...
]
```

or ***adding***

```
"include": [
    ...
]
```

Makes huge improvements when running `npm run lint` / `ng lint`.

In my case `time TIMING=1 npx eslint ./src/` or `time ng lint` was running for exactly the same time.